# Différences entre « facultatif » et « optionnel »

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Quelles sont les différences entre le mot « facultatif » et le mot « optionnel » ? J'ai consulté un dictionnaire mais je ne comprends pas encore les différences.

Ceci est la définition pour « facultatif » :

> Qu'on a la liberté de faire ou de ne pas faire.

Et ceci est la définition pour « optionnel » :

> Qui donne lieu à un choix, qui résulte d'une option.

Les deux mots se traduisent par « optional » en anglais. Quelle est la différence ? Quel mot est approprié pour la création d'un formulaire ?

Note: This is my first time writing a post on Stack Exchange in French, I hope it was comprehensible. Feel free to correct me on anything and an English explanation for my question would also be appreciated. Merci!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Les deux termes sont assez proches mais pas toujours interchangeables.

***Facultatif*** indique quelque chose de prévu/inclus mais pas obligatoire, alors qu'***optionnel*** correspond à quelque chose qui s'ajoute à ce qui est prévu.

Par exemple :

- *Cours d'anglais facultatifs* : ceux qui maîtrisent déjà l'anglais n'ont pas besoin d'y assister, ils y perdraient leur temps.
- *Cours d'anglais optionnels* : ceux qui maîtrisent déjà l'anglais peuvent les choisir pour s'améliorer et/ou éventuellement gagner des points supplémentaires.

Le contraire de **facultatif** est **obligatoire** ou **indispensable** alors que le contraire d'**optionnel** peut être, suivant le contexte, **standard** ou **de série**, mais aussi **obligatoire**.

---

Both terms are close, but rarely interchangeable.

A distinction is "***facultatif***" would be used for something planned/included but not mandatory while "***optionnel***" would apply to something that is an addition to the plan.

For example:

- "*Cours de français facultatifs*": those already fluent with French do not need to attend, they would waste their time.
- "*Cours de français optionnels*": those already fluent with French might decide to attend anyway in order to study further and/or improve their overall rating.

The opposite of ***facultatif*** is ***obligatoire*** (mandatory) or ***indispensable*** while the opposite of ***optionnel*** might be, depending on the context, ***standard*** or ***de série***, but also ***obligatoire***.

Answer (score 6):

L'usage de ces mots est souvent similaire, mais il n'est pas identique.

Optionnel se réfère au fait de **choisir** entre deux ou plusieurs options (quoique souvent ce soit entre faire quelques chose et ne rien faire, en finances par ex). Ce qui est facultatif est quelque chose que l'on **n'est pas obligé de faire**. *Optionnel* est un terme beaucoup plus récent, d'ailleurs probablement calqué sur l'anglais, et sa sémantique est donc moins bien établie. Dans beaucoup de cas, c'est un usage un peu *ad hoc*.

Dans le cas d'un formulaire, on emploiera donc *facultatif*, puisqu'il s'agit clairement d'une section qu'il n'est pas obligatoire de compléter.

Comment: Quelle est la différence entre _choix de faire ou pas_ et _pas obligé de faire_?

Comment: Je préférerais définir facultatif de façon positive en disant que c'est quelque chose que l'on peut faire. Par exemple un arrêt facultatif est un arrêt où le bus s'arrête si un client le demande (par contre le chauffeur est obligé de s'arrêter sous peine de perdre son emploi).

Comment: Ceci est la *bonne* reponse, a mon avis.

Answer (score 1):

Dans le cadre d'un formulaire, l'usage est d'utiliser le mot **facultatif**. Je n'ai pas de référence précise mais je me base sur les nombreux sites sur lesquels le mot **facultatif** est utilisé. Voici quelques exemples :

- Wikipédia :

  [image: Facultative]
- Amazon.fr :

  [image: Facultatif]

Comment: Please add an explanation if you down-voted. Merci d'ajouter une explication si vous avez voté négativement.